# Nuxt : how can i call a method if the document is ready (all css already loaded)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nuxt.js

I need to call the function after the document is ready, because i need access to the css class dot.

```js
mounted () {
    $(this).ready(function () {
      this.methods.addSlick()
    })
},
methods: {
    addSlick () {
      $(this.$refs.yourClass).slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        mobileFirst: true,
        ininite: false,
        dots: true,
        customPaging (slider, i) {
          return '<span class="dot">s</span>'
        }
      })
    }
}
```

Error in the Console:

```js
    jquery.js?1157:3827 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addSlick')
        at HTMLDocument.eval (ProductSlider.vue?5b8f:30:1)
        at mightThrow (jquery.js?1157:3534:1)
        at process (jquery.js?1157:3602:1)
    eval @ ProductSlider.vue?5b8f:30
    mightThrow @ jquery.js?1157:3534
    process @ jquery.js?1157:3602
    setTimeout (async)
```

Answer (score 0):

the error message tells you that you are trying to access `addSlick` of `undefined`, that means `this.methods` in your first code block is undefined. This happens, because you're wrapping it in a jQuery `ready` call which changes the `this` context which is not what you want here. The `ready` call is not necessary, because if you execute something in `mounted` you can be sure that your ref `yourClass` is available in the dom.

If you remove lines 2 and 4 from your first code block the error message should be fixed.